# How does 37signals make the day change on their homepage

Tags: javascript, html

37signals has a sort of greeting at the top of their homepage (http://www.37signals.com). It says "Happy (today's day).

My question is how do they make the day change.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can easily see this by right clicking on the page and view source:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  <!-- 
  // Array of day names
  var dayNames = new Array("Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday",
                "Thursday","Friday","Saturday");
  var now = new Date();
  document.write("Happy " + dayNames[now.getDay()] + ".");
  // -->
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

They probably use PHP to get the day like so

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/London");
$day = date("l");
echo "Happy " . $day;


?>
```

Comment: you can do it this way, but @usefulcat's answer is how 37Signals actually do it with JavaScript

Comment: And I would say it's Ruby if they were doing it on the server side.